# enable authentication in hawtio deployed on jetty

Tags: java, jetty, hawtio

I'v setup jetty and added a HashLoginService which uses the realm.properties..basically the demo setup.
I'm using the hawtio-web.war where I set the **hawtio.authenticationEnabled** to true. 
Problem is that I'm not able to login. The login page of hawtio appears but it always says "forbidden"...I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for figuring this out and contributing to hawtio how to do this. See this link -> https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#configuring-security-in-jetty

Comment: The one thing that is not clear from the document to me is where you set the hawtio properties in jetty? E.g hawtio.authenticationEnabled=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Claus already mentioned configuration details can be found here:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#configuring-security-in-jetty

thanks for the support :)